# Array from Controller to model [codeIgniter]

Tags: codeigniter

here's my problem:

Codeigniter's doc says this :

```
<?php

    $array = array('name' => $name, 'title' => $title, 'status' => $status);

    $this->db->where($array);

    // Produces: WHERE name = 'Joe' AND title = 'boss' AND status = 'active'

?>
```

I just want to pass conditions to my where clause from controller to model so :

**Controller**

```
<?php
    $condition = array('id' => $id_user)
    $data['info_user'] = $this->user_model->get_user($condition);
?>
```

**Model**

```
public function get_user($condition)
{
    $q = $this
        ->db
        ->where($condition)
        ->get('users');

    if($q->num_rows > 0)
    {
        return $q->row();
    }
}
```

This return : **SELECT * FROM (`users`) WHERE `3` IS NULL**

But when I put my array directly in the model ($

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to pass an array and I'm not even positive that it can be done the way you're trying to do it. Just pass the value itself to the model as below. Answer edited to show multiple variables.

Controller:

```
   $data['info_user'] = $this->user_model->get_user($id_user,$user_login);
```

Model:

```
public function get_user($id_user,$user_login)
{
    $q = $this
        ->db
        ->where('id_user',$id_user)
        ->or_where('user_login',$user_login);
        ->get('users');

    if($q->num_rows == 1)
    {
        return $q->row();
    }
}
```

As a side note when you want a single result from your database, as in retrieving a user ALWAYS check for a single result and not > 0. You want to ensure you're only getting one user back.

Comment: Well, that's not the solution I'm looking for :

I want to pass an array so I can get user by either his login or ID.

What are my options ?

Ps : thanks for the correction on num_rows == 1, you're right

Comment: okay... you're looking for what exactly then? Because the way you posted isn't going to work.

Comment: (I pressed enter too soon :) )

Comment: Pass the values separately, the problem with the way you're doing it is you can't pass an array to a function like that. I'll edit the answer, sec.

Comment: Ok, that's what I did. It's strange tho that you can't pass array to the model no ?

Comment: I am 99% positive you can't in the way you were trying to no, I do believe that value in the function is taken as a single value. I could be wrong, but I never do it that way honestly and I have functions that take half a dozen conditions.

Comment: Glad I could help, just one thing to keep in mind when doing it the way I said, both values will need to be sent to the model even if you don't have both since the model reads them in order, so if you just sent the user_login the model would think it was the userId. Good Luck!!